# gdal_rasterize -at function still won't capture covered pixels properly

Tags: raster, gdal, polygon

I'm currently using the gdal_rasterize tool in bash. My code looks like this:

```
gdal_rasterize -l $(basename $file .shp) -burn 1  -a_nodata 0 -te -180 -90 180 90 -tr 0.1 0.01 -at -ot Byte $file $OUTPUT/rast_2.tif
```

I was hoping that the `-at` function would give a '1' burn value to any pixel touched by the input shapefile. However, this is what the comparison looks like:

[image: Areas not rasterized properly]

Is this the a problem with the -at ALL_TOUCHED function or should I be doing something differently to ensure that all areas are accounted for?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What version of GDAL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Peculiar, I would just post a comment but apparently I don't have enough points.  Two questions: What version of gdal and is the output exactly the same without '-at'?